# Search on resume

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that lets the user write keyword and search videos related to that.
When I click on a video to start play it, it opens Video Activity and plays it.
The problem is when I'm pressing the back button to choose another video, I need to click search again.
I tried to use onResume method and but it's not working properly.
Any ideas?
Here is the onResume:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideKeyboard(); // a method to hide the keyboard.
    mServiceTask = new ServiceTask(SEARCH_VIDEO);
    mServiceTask.setmServerResponseListener(this);
    mServiceTask.execute(new Object[]{postKeyword}); // postKeyword is the keyword the user entered.
}
```

Here is the method that plays the video:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    SearchResult result = (SearchResult)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    VIDEO_ID = result.getId().getVideoId();
    Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this,AppConstants.KEY,VIDEO_ID);
    startActivity(videoIntent);
}
```

Hope you guys could help me.
Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Can you post the method starting the Video Activity.

Comment: try `onActivityResult`

Comment: show the code of vedio listing, You should call the vedio listing in onCreate  method, may be you done this onStart method.

Comment: @AC-OpenSource I'm now editing the source so you can see.

Comment: @nmxprime thanks, I tried,  It won't even get to onActivityResult.

Comment: @QadirHussain Thanks but I get the videos on onClick method triggerd by a button.

Comment: override `onBackPressed()` and call  `super.onBackPressed();` in your video activity

Comment: Keep your list /array list / arrays static, this will not empty your data carriers on starting new actvity

Comment: @Rustam Kinda sad, but I already tried that one, didn't work neither..

Comment: @QadirHussain Thanks, I will try, will give back feedback in about an hour or so.

Comment: Ah, actually onActivityResult will be triggered iff an activity is started by startActivityForResult

Comment: @QadirHussain because this method is related to a lot more things in the code, it is kinda problem to use static.

Comment: Are you using fragments?